# How do I add a new Table or Grid to a WPF TableCell?

Tags: c#, wpf, tablecell

I currently can add text to my WPF table cell using:

```
cell.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Example Text")));
```

What I'd like is to be able to add an object within the cell such as another table or a grid.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a `Grid` to a `TableCell`... `TableCell` can only host elements deriving from [Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.aspx)

[MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.tablecell.aspx)

> TableCell elements may host one or more flow content elements deriving
>   from Block. Valid content elements for a TableCell include:

- BlockUIContainer
- List
- Paragraph
- Section
- Table

The easisest way to add other elements to `TableCell` is in XAML...

```
<TableCell><Paragraph FontSize="14pt" FontWeight="Bold">Planet</Paragraph></TableCell>
```

Comment: Table was one of my options.  So how would I add it?  (BTW, I'm extending a dynamically created table so I can't use XAML)

Comment: Just nest it inside the TableCell... <TableCell><Table>...</Table></TableCell>

Comment: Well that may work in XAML, but in the code it won't let me.  Something like "cell.Blocks.Add(new Table());"  Doesn't work

Comment: I appreciate that but I'm asking my question here because I can't find how to do it anywhere online.

Comment: Create the new table and whatever else in it, then add the table to the cell blocks the same way you added the Paragraph to the cell blocks: `Table table = new Table(); cell.Blocks.Add(table);`

Answer (score 0):

By doing this you can add nested table.First of all you create outer table then you create inner table.You create table row group for adding row.And then create an instance of the TableRow.Then add this row to the TableRowGroup.The last step is to add this TableRowGroup in outer Tabel.
Like :

```
       Table outTable=new Table ();
       Table innerTable=new Table ();
        TableRowGroup rg = new TableRowGroup();
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Section(innerTabe)));
        rg.Rows.Add(tr);
        outTable.RowGroups.Add(rg);
```